# Don't open an IPython console when I open Spyder

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I am using Spyder 2.3.7 with Python 2.7.10 and Pandas 0.17.0.  When I open Spyder, IPython console connects to a Kernel and opens.  I don't want to use IPython through Spyder.  Is there a way I can make it so it does not try to open when I start Spyder?  How can I change the entry point from IPython?  I just want it to use the Console when I start it up, and only open IPython when I specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) To not load an IPython console by default, you need to close its corresponding pane by pressing the `x` button on its top right corner, as shown in the image below

[image]

Then you need to close Spyder and start it again.

Comment: I was clicking the Red X and not the Gray X.  This works great.  Thanks for the help!